# Using exe or DLL for calling program from another program

Tags: c++, dll, exe

I have a big program A that at some point calls my (big) program B. Program B is called only once in Program A. At the moment Program B is an executable Program (B.exe - compiled C++-Code).

Somebody proposed using a DLL of Program B instead of using the executable.

- Are there any advantages in using a DLL ( like security, size, etc.)
- Is it easy to create a DLL from my source-code ( I use Qt creator)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Are there any advantages in using a dll ( like security, size, etc)

No. As a matter of fact, if you're looking at things like security, size, etc. using a DLL makes things worse. When you load a DLL, everything happens inside the loading process' address space. So any bug inside the DLL directly affects the rest of the program. A crash in the DLL code, will crash the whole program.

> Is it easy to create a dll from my source-code ( I use Qt creator)

Yes it is. But to me it seems there's hardly any benefit for your particular use case. As a matter of fact, for rarely used code paths I'd rather strongly encourage putting it into a separate process (i.e. link it into a .EXE).

BTW: `.dll` and `.exe` are exactly the same. You can load a `.exe` as if it were a DLL; give it a `DllMain` and you can use it either way! Of course loading a EXE with `LoadLibrary` won't make it run in a separate process and rather import all the bugs into your main program.